# How to show file writing progress percentage in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesystems

```
var csv = json2csv(datas, fields);
  var path = './final_' + Date.now() + '.csv';
  fs.writeFile(path, csv, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    else {
      console.log('File created >> ' + path)
    }
  });
```

Above code is use for generating CSV file and writing into it. This code is working perfectlly.

> But i am trying to show in percentage or anything of progress of
>   writing in csv.
>   and i am trying to show it only in **Commandprompt**
>   using **console.log()**
>
> How can i achive this?

Comment: You should be looking at the fs.createWriteStream which emits the progress event.

Comment: @SharanMohandas can share me an example on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) library in order to see upload file progress in percentage. This library should get your things done.

This library gets the length of the stream automatically if you're using the request or http module. You can also pass the length on initiation